# Nested flutter GestureDetectors are not working

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

The simple code snippet I want to implement is below

```dart
class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onScaleUpdate: _onScaleUpdate,
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onScaleEnd: _onScaleEnd,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.orange
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  _onScaleUpdate(ScaleUpdateDetails details) async {
    print("_onScaleUpdate");
  }
  _onScaleEnd(ScaleEndDetails details) async {
    print("_onScaleEnd ${details.pointerCount}");
  }
}
```

Only the method `_onScaleEnd` is calling. How to make them work both?
I have not any ideas but `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent`. But it does not help

Comment: why are you using 2 `GestureDetector`s?

Comment: It is a simplified example. The original problem has too long code to paste it here